# C#, Writing longer method or shorter method?

Tags: c#, .net, methods

I am getting two contradicting views on this. Some source says there should be less little methods to reduce method calls, but some other source says writing shorter method is good for letting the JIT to do the optimization.

So, which side is correct?

Answer (score 30):

The overhead of actually making the method call is inconsequentially small in most every case. You never need to worry about it unless you can clearly identify a problem down the road that requires revisiting the issue (you won't).

It's far more important that your code is simple, readable, modular, maintainable, and modifiable. Methods should do one thing, one thing only and delegate sub-things to other routines. This means your methods should be as short as they can possibly be, but not any shorter. You will see far more performance benefits by having code that is less prone to error and bugs because it is simple, than by trying to outsmart the compiler or the runtime.

The source that says methods should be long is **wrong**, on many levels.

Answer (score 8):

None, you should have relatively short method to achieve *readability*.

Answer (score 3):

There is no one simple rule about function size. The guideline should be a function should do 'one thing'. That's a little vague but becomes easier with experience. Small functions generally lead to readability. Big ones are occasionally necessary.

Worrying about the overhead of method calls is premature optimization.

Answer (score 2):

As always, it's about finding a good balance. The most important thing is that **the method does one thing only**. Longer methods tend to do more than one thing.

Answer (score 2):

The best single criterion to guide you in sizing methods is to **keep them well-testable**.  If you can (and actually DO!-) thoroughly unit-test every single method, your code is likely to be quite good; if you skimp on testing, your code is likely to be, at best, mediocre.  If a method is difficult to test thoroughly, then that method is likely to be "too big" -- trying to do too many things, and therefore also harder to read and maintain (as well as badly-tested and therefore a likely haven for bugs).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should definitely not be micro-optimizing the performance on the number-of-methods level. You will most likely not get any measurable performance benefit. Only if you have some method that are being called in a tight loop millions of times, it might be an idea - but don't begin optimizing on that before you need it.

You should stick to short concise methods, that does one thing, that makes the intent of the method clear. This will give you easier-to-read code, that is easier to understand and promotes code reuse.

Answer (score 1):

The most important cost to consider when writing code is maintanability.  You will spend *much*, *much* more time maintaining an application and fixing bugs than you ever will fixing performance problems.

In this case the almost certainly insignificant cost of calling a method is incredibly small when compared to the cost of maintaining a large unwieldy method.  Small concise methods are easier to maintain and comprehend.  Additionally the cost of calling the method almost certainly will not have a significant performance impact on your application.  And if it does, you can only assertain that by using a profiler.  Developers are notoriously bad at identifying performance problems before hand.

Generally speaking, once a performance problem is identified, they are easy to fix.  Making a method or more importantly a code base, maintainable is a much higher cost.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I am not afraid of long methods as long as the person writing them writes them well (every piece of sub-task separated by 2 newlines and a nice comment preceeding it, etc. Also, identation is very important.).
In fact, many times I even prefer them (e.g. when writing code that does things in a specific order with sequential logic).

Also, I really don't understand why breaking a long method into 100 pieces will improve readablility (as others suggest). Only the opposite. You will only end-up jumping all over the place and holding pieces of code in your memory just to get a complete picture of what is going on in your code. Combine that with possible lack of comments, bad function names, many similar function names and you have the perfect recipe for chaos.
Also, you could go the other end while trying to reduce the size of the methods: to create MANY classes and MANY functions each of which may take MANY parameters. I don't think this improves readability either (especially for a begginer to a project that has no clue what each class/method do).

And the demand that "a function should do 'one thing'" is very subjective. 'One thing' may be increasing a variable by one up to doing a ton of work supposedly for the 'same thing'.

My rule is only reuseability:
The same code should not appear many times in many places. If this is the case you need a new function.
All the rest is just philosophical talk.
In a question of "why do you make your methods so big" I reply, "why not if the code is simple?".